# Integer-to-ASCII algorithm (x86 assembly)

Tags: formatting, integer, assembly

This is my best effort at converting a 32 bit integer in `EAX`, to an 8 character ascii string (result in `RDI`).  It will work accurately up to 99,999,999.  Higher values could be done using an `xmm` register.  The byte order in `RDI` is correct (e.g. if copied directly to video ram, the most significant byte is displayed first)  No expensive `DIV` instructions or memory accesses required.  Can this be improved further?

```
    mov ebx, 0xCCCCCCCD             
    xor rdi, rdi
.loop:
    mov ecx, eax                    ; save original number

    mul ebx                         ; divide by 10 using agner fog's 'magic number'
    shr edx, 3                      ;

    mov eax, edx                    ; store it back into eax

    lea edx, [edx*4 + edx]          ; multiply by 10
    lea edx, [edx*2 - '0']          ; and ascii it
    sub ecx, edx                    ; subtract from original number to get remainder

    shl rdi, 8                      ; shift in to least significant byte
    or rdi, rcx                     ;

    test eax, eax
    jnz .loop
```

Comment: What constitutes an "improvement?"  Smaller code?  Faster code? Error checking?  I can make it smaller by using div, faster (on my hw) by moving things around, and checking for overflow would be trivial.  There are some comments that could be improved too.

Comment: Faster is the criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all sorts of things that LOOK like they should perform better, but I can only get a tiny bit of improvement.  And that may disappear (or worsen) on other hardware:

```
    mov ebx, 0xCCCCCCCD             
    xor rdi, rdi

.loop:
    mov ecx, eax                    ; save original number

    mul ebx                         ; divide by 10 using agner fog's 'magic number'
    shr edx, 3                      ;

    mov eax, edx                    ; store quotient for next loop

    lea edx, [edx*4 + edx]          ; multiply by 10
    shl rdi, 8                      ; make room for byte
    lea edx, [edx*2 - '0']          ; finish *10 and convert to ascii
    sub ecx, edx                    ; subtract from original number to get remainder

    lea rdi, [rdi + rcx]            ; store next byte

    test eax, eax
    jnz .loop
```

The 2 changes are:

- Move `shl rdi` to a 'better' place
- Use `lea` instead of `or` to set rdi

Comment: I understand moving the `shl rdi` but how is `lea` faster than `or`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer is "I don't know why it's faster, I just tried it and it works."  `or` (presumably) uses a different pipeline, or has different dependencies than `lea`.  Given the "out-of-order" execution of today's processors, it's hard for mere mortals to understand how anything works anymore.  That's (one reason) why most people use higher level languages.  The people who write the compiler's optimizers understand this crap so the rest of us don't have to.  The days when you could just dash off a few lines of asm that performed better then the C output are long gone.

Comment: Why use `lea` here at all? Why not just `add rdi, rcx`? Also, `xor rdi, rdi` should be `xor edi, edi` since that will implicitly clear the upper 32 bits but is shorter because it doesn't require the REX prefix.