# Console TicTacToe implementation

Tags: beginner, tic-tac-toe, assembly, x86

I am new to assembly and I want to know how I can improve this implementation both by speed and/or binary size optimization and making code to read and support easily.

**Platform**: Linux, x64

**Assembler**: NASM

**Code**
    section .data

```
; Consts
%define XChar 'X'
%define OChar 'O'
%define filler '+'
%define LF 0x0a
%define separatorChars " -:,.;"

%define stdin 0x00
%define stdout 0x01

X: db XChar
O: db OChar
currentTurn: db XChar

; Buffers.
field: times 9 db filler

; Strings.
lineFeed: db LF
coordSeparators: db separatorChars
coordSeparatorsL: equ $ - coordSeparators

choosePlayerStr: db "Choose your character - type X or O: "
choosePlayerStrL: equ $ - choosePlayerStr
makeTurn: db 'Enter cell coord delimited by space: ',
makeTurnL: equ $ - makeTurn
boundsError: db 'Coords should be in range 1-3.', LF
boundsErrorL: equ $ - boundsError
cellUsedError: db 'Cell on specified coords is already used.', LF
cellUsedErrorL: equ $ - cellUsedError
separatorNotExistsError: db "Use one of '", separatorChars, "' characters between the coords.", LF
separatorNotExistsErrorL: equ $ - separatorNotExistsError
winStr: db " win!", LF
winStrL: equ $ - winStr
separatorStr: db "---------------------------", LF
separatorStrL: equ $ - separatorStr
drawStr: db "Draw!", LF
drawStrL: equ $ - drawStr

section .bss
    buf: resb 256 ; Buffer for user input.

section .text

%macro writeChar 1
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, stdout
    mov rsi, %1
    mov rdx, 0x01
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro writeConsole 1
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, stdout
    mov rsi, %1
    mov rdx, %1L
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro readConsole 0
    mov rax, 0x00
    mov rdi, stdin
    mov rsi, buf
    mov rdx, 256
    syscall
%endmacro

global _start
_start:
    call printField

chooseCharacter:
    writeConsole choosePlayerStr
    readConsole

    cmp byte [buf], XChar
    je characterChosen

    cmp byte [buf], OChar
    je characterChosen

    jmp chooseCharacter

characterChosen:
    mov al, [buf]
    mov byte [currentTurn], al

nextTurn:
    writeConsole makeTurn
    readConsole

    mov rcx, coordSeparatorsL
checkCoordSeparator:
    mov al, byte [buf + 1]
    cmp al, byte [rcx + coordSeparators - 1]
    je processUserInput

    dec rcx
    cmp rcx, 0
    jg checkCoordSeparator

    writeConsole separatorNotExistsError
    jmp nextTurn

processUserInput:
    movzx r8, byte [buf]
    movzx r9, byte [buf + 2]
    sub r8, '0'
    sub r9, '0'

    call makeMove

    ; Save move result (success/fail) in r12, because other registers will
    ; be used by printField of affected by syscall.
    mov r12, rax
    call printField

    ; If move was failed - make turn again.
    cmp r12, 0
    jne nextTurn

checkForDraw:
    mov rcx, 9 ; Max number of loops
    mov al, filler
    mov rdi, field
    repne scasb

    cmp rcx, 0
    je draw

    ; Check for win.
    ; 1. Check columns.
    xor cl, cl; Counter.

nextColumn:
    mov al, byte [rcx + field] ; Copy 1st cell to al.

    ; Cell shouldn't contain filler.
    cmp al, filler
    je endIteration

    cmp al, byte [rcx + field + 3]
    jne endIteration

    cmp al, byte [rcx + field + 6]
    je win

endIteration:
    inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 0x03
    jl nextColumn

    ; 2. Check rows.
    xor cl, cl ; Counter.

nextRow:
    mov al, byte [rcx * 3 + field] ; Copy 1st cell to al.

    ; Cell shouldn't contain filler.
    cmp al, filler
    je endRowIteration

    cmp al, byte [rcx * 3 + field + 1]
    jne endRowIteration

    cmp al, byte [rcx * 3 + field + 2]
    je win

endRowIteration:
    inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 0x03
    jl nextRow

    ; 3. Check diagonals.
    ; 3.1. Check 1st (\) diagonal.
    mov al, byte [field] ; Copy 1st cell to al.

    ; Cell shouldn't contain filler.
    cmp al, filler
    je secondDiagonalCheck

    cmp al, byte [field + 4]
    jne secondDiagonalCheck

    cmp al, byte [field + 8]
    je win

; 3.2. Check 2nd (/) diagonal.
secondDiagonalCheck:
    mov al, byte [field + 2] ; Copy 1st cell to al.

    ; Cell shouldn't contain filler.
    cmp al, filler
    je endDiagonalCheck

    cmp al, byte [field + 4]
    jne endDiagonalCheck

    cmp al, byte [field + 6]
    je win

endDiagonalCheck:
    ; Change current player.
    cmp byte [currentTurn], XChar
    cmove rax, [O]
    cmovne rax, [X]
    mov byte [currentTurn], al

    jmp nextTurn

draw:
    writeConsole separatorStr
    writeConsole drawStr
    jmp exit

win:
    writeConsole separatorStr
    writeChar currentTurn
    writeConsole winStr

exit:
    ; return 0
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0x00
    syscall

; ================================================
; void printField()
printField:
    xor bx, bx

printRow:
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    lea rsi, [ebx + ebx * 2 + field]
    mov rdx, 0x03
    syscall

    writeChar lineFeed

    inc bx
    cmp bx, byte 3
    jnz printRow

    ret
; ================================================

; ================================================
; makeMove(int8 row, int8 col)
;
; r8: row coord
; r9: column coord
makeMove:
    ; Indexing start with 0, then we should decrement both
    dec r8
    dec r9

    ; Checking bounds.
    cmp r8, 0
    jl outOfBoundsError
    cmp r9, 0
    jl outOfBoundsError
    cmp r8, 3
    jge outOfBoundsError
    cmp r9, 3
    jge outOfBoundsError

    ; Check if used.
    mov rsi, r8
    add rsi, r9
    cmp byte [rsi + r8*2 + field], filler
    jne usedCellError

    ; Set cell.
    mov rax, [currentTurn]
    mov byte [rsi + r8*2 + field], al

    xor rax, rax
    jmp makeMoveEnd

; Errors.
outOfBoundsError:
    writeConsole boundsError

    mov rax, 1
    jmp makeMoveEnd

usedCellError:
    writeConsole cellUsedError

    mov rax, 1
    jmp makeMoveEnd

makeMoveEnd:
    ret
; ================================================
```

**Codeflow (not very detailed)**
[image: ttt codeflow]

Comment: Perhaps you could start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/2189500).

Answer (score 2):

1) When zeroing registers, it takes less code to do `xor eax, eax` than `mov eax, 0`, and it runs (microscopically) faster.  There's also a trick:  While `eax` is usually just thought of as "the lower 32bits of rax," if you do `xor eax, eax` it implicitly zeros all 64 bits, and assembles to fewer bytes.

2) Looking at this code:

```
cmp byte [buf], OChar
je characterChosen

jmp chooseCharacter

characterChosen:
```

Consider restructuring it like this:

```
cmp byte [buf], OChar
jne chooseCharacter

characterChosen:
```

If it doesn't take the `jne`, it just continues on to the next statement.  So doing things this way saves you from executing an extra jump.

3) Consider this code:

```
dec rcx
cmp rcx, 0
jg checkCoordSeparator
```

The way `cmp` works is that it sets some flags.  When `jg` is executed, it looks at the current values of the flags to figure out what to do.  But `cmp` isn't the only instruction that sets the flags.  So does `dec`.  Such being the case, you might try something like:

```
dec rcx
jnz checkCoordSeparator
```

Any time you find yourself doing a `cmp`, check to see if you have just done some math that would already set the flags for you so you can save time and not set them again.

For example sometimes you can restructure your loops: Instead of counting up from 0 to 3 (and comparing with 3), you can count down from 3 to 0 and use this trick.  It does the same amount of work, but executes 1 fewer instruction.

4) I'm not sure what's in 'rcx' at that point, but it probably doesn't need the full 64bits that "rcx" can hold.  If you don't expect the value to get bigger than about 2,147,483,647, using the 32bit version of instruction "ecx" can be a bit of a savings.  Note that moving down to the 16bit version (cx) doesn't get more savings, and can be worse.

5) "I'm not sure what's in 'rcx' at that point" - And the reason I'm not sure, is that you don't have any comments there.  Asm is particularly hard for humans to read.  Instead of using names that humans can understand (ie "NumberOfMoves"), you get to use register names (ie 'rcx').  What's worse is that since there are only a few registers, you use them for a bunch of different things, so it's not always clear exactly what you are doing at any given point without reading all the code around it.

That's why well-written assembler is *filled* with comments; often every line ends with a comment saying what it's doing (something like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142910/110050)).

While it may be clear to you what this code does (since you just wrote it), when other people read your code (or if you read it again 6 months from now), it makes things much easier.

6) Then there's this:

```
cmp rcx, 0
je draw
```

When checking to see if a register is zero, this code is (slightly) smaller:

```
test rcx, rcx
je draw
```

It assembles to 1 fewer byte (2 fewer if you can use ecx instead of rcx).

---

Note that the suggestions above all (slightly) improve the size and (imperceptibly) improve the performance of your code, but they aren't going to change the results.  It's not that what you are doing is going to give the wrong answer, it's just not the most efficient way.  Oddly you seem to use some of these methods in some places and not others?

IAC, nowadays, it's almost always better to write your code in high level languages (like C) and let the compiler figure out all this stuff for you.  They already know all these tricks (and a thousand more).  Learning assembler is useful, but the more you learn, the more you realize that humans shouldn't be writing in assembler anymore.

Comment: Thanks for useful advices. I will fix it ASAP. I agree about nowadays and high level languages, but we should mention that writing assembly code still could be useful to better reverse engineering learning.